# How to make autoscale_view respect text

Tags: python, matplotlib

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

ax.add_patch(...) # several times
ax.text(x,y,"something") # several times
ax.autoscale_view()
```

truncates text. I.e. it does not respect text position, width and height in viewport calculations.

How to make autoscale_view respect ax.text(...) calls?